# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\int_{a}^{b} f(nx))=\frac{b-a}{T}\int_0^T f(x)dx$ when $f$ is continuous and periodic

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \colon R \to R $ a continuous and periodic function, with period $T$.
Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\int_{a}^{b} f(nx)dx)=\frac{b-a}{T}\int_0^T f(x)dx$, con  $a < b$.

I know that $\forall a \in R, \ \int_a^{a+T}f(x)dx=\int_0^T f(x)dx$, so maybe I can use this result for this proof.

Comment: Hint: prove it when $f$ takes two distinct values (and is piecewise continuous and $T$-periodic). Then prove it when $f$ is $T$-periodic and piecewise constant. Then prove it when $f$ is continuous by approximation.

Comment: @Mindlack: You're thinking of the more general Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. This is quite a bit easier.

Comment: Indeed. I had not seen any easier way, but there is one, thanks for pointing it out. @ OP: for any large $n$, split $[a,b]$ into $T/n$-length intervals, and some remainder that is of length $<T/n$. Each interval contributes $1/n*Af$, where $Af$ is the average value of $f$, there are $\sim n(b-a)/T$ intervals and the remainder contributes $o(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Use a substitution: $\int_a^b f(nx)\,dx = \frac1n\int_{na}^{nb}f(t)\,dt$.

Now, if $m=\left\lfloor\frac{n(b-a)}{T}\right\rfloor$ is the number of full periods that can fit into an interval of length $nb-na$, we have
$$\int_{na}^{nb}f(t)\,dt = \int_{na}^{na+mT}f(t)\,dt + \int_{na+mT}^{nb}f(t)\,dt = m\int_0^T f(t)\,dt + \int_{na+mT}^{nb}f(t)\,dt$$
The interval from $na+mT$ to $nb$ has length less than $T$, so the integral of $f$ on it is no more than $CT$ in absolute value, where $C$ is the supremum of $f$ over a period. Therefore (bringing that factor of $\frac1n$ back in),
$$\left|\frac1n\int_{na}^{nb}f(t)\,dt - \frac1n\left\lfloor\frac{n(b-a)}{T}\right\rfloor\int_0^T f(t)\,dt\right| < \frac{CT}{n}$$
Take the limit as $n\to\infty$, and we have $\frac1n\left\lfloor\frac{n(b-a)}{T}\right\rfloor\to \frac{b-a}{T}$ and $\frac{CT}{n}\to 0$, leaving us with
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f(nx)\,dx =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\int_{na}^{nb}f(t)\,dt = \frac{b-a}{T}\int_0^T f(t)\,dt$$

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy if you know that $f$ can be approximated uniformly by linear combinations of the functions $e^{i\frac {2\pi} T kx}$. For this last function both sides are $0$ of $k \neq 0$ and $b-a$ if $k=0$.

Comment: The result i have used is called Fejer's Theorem and it can be found in Baby Rudin.